# Vector doesn't add values

Tags: c++, vector

It's a simple program in which I'm initializing a vector by passing it by reference to a function and then finding the max value. The values in the vector still remain zeros however and do not update to the ones provided via console input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void initialize(vector<int>& v) {
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter the value " << (i + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> n;
        v.push_back(n);
    }
}

int findMax(vector<int>& v, int& max) {
    int iMax = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (v[i] > max) {
            cout << endl << "v[" << i << "] = " << v[i] << endl;
            max = v[i];
            iMax = i;
        }
    }
    return iMax;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v(10);
    initialize(v);
    int max = v[0];
    int x = findMax(v, max);
    cout << "The maximum value is " << max << " and is strored at the index position " << x << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In findMax, you're skipping through item 0 because your loop starts at i = 1. In your test data, is the first element the max and are rest of them zeros?

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<int> v(10);
```

makes the first 10 elements be 0. Then you are using `push_back` in `initialize`, which adds elements 11-th through 20-th.

You can fix it by changing the above line to:

```
vector<int> v;
```

or by using

```
v[i] = n;
```

in `initialize`

Comment: I love you Sahu. Thank you so much. You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

Push_back on already initialized vector is not needed. Go ahead and use either iterator or index and step through it and replace the values.

I would suggest just a declaration vector v; and than using push_back as the program becomes more universal and you do not need to know the vector size right at the start!